# Single query filtering

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following two tables:

Manager table:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Employee table:

| id | manager | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | ACTIVE |
| 5 | 3 | ACTIVE |
| 6 | 3 | INACTIVE |
| 7 | 1 | ACTIVE |
| 8 | 1 | ACTIVE |

Is it possible to select in a single query only managers which have all employees with status = 'ACTIVE'?

For example, I want only manager with id 1, and not manager with id 3 (having employee with id 6 with status = 'INACTIVE').

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: There's no row with manager = 2 in your EMPLOYEE table. Also, why wouldn't you want to select manager 1 (its statuses are also only ACTIVE)? So ... description doesn't match data. Fix *something*.

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns Managers having ACTIVE employees and no INACTIVE employees. Managers with employees are excluded.

```
SELECT m.id 
FROM Manager m
JOIN Employee e
on m.id = e.manager
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
AND m.id NOT IN
  (SELECT manager 
   FROM employee
   WHERE Status = 'INACTIVE')
GROUP BY m.id;
```

The following query returns Managers not having INACTIVE employees, which means that is returns managers with no employees.

```
SELECT id 
FROM Manager
WHERE id NOT IN
  (SELECT manager 
   FROM employee
   WHERE Status = 'INACTIVE');
```

Comment: Your query returns managers from managers table that are not in employees table too, for example if there is manager with id 999 he will be in your result because his id is not in `SELECT manager 
   FROM employee
   WHERE Status = 'INACTIVE'`

Comment: @Toni Antunovic Yes - I explained that is my answer. The second query returns managers "not having inactive exmployees" which includes "managers with no employees".

Comment: Ups didn t see explanation, my bad, but I understood OP that he wants a query to show only managers with employees and active status.

Comment: @ToniAntunovic that's what I thought but it's not clear so I gave both options.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
select ma.id 
from manager ma
cross apply (select count(*) c from employee where ma.manager = employee.code)q1
cross apply (select count(*) c from employee where ma.manager = employee.code and employee.status = 'ACTIVE') q2
where q1.c = q2.c
```

You are just checking if the count of all employees is the same with the count of all active employees, for the same manager of course

Comment: Does Oracle support cross apply?

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY` the `manager_id` and then use conditional aggregation to find the groups where there are active employees and no inactive employees:

```sql
SELECT manager
FROM   employees
GROUP BY manager
HAVING COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) > 0
AND    COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'INACTIVE' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE managers (id) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;

CREATE TABLE employees (id, manager, Status) AS
SELECT 4, 3, 'ACTIVE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 3, 'ACTIVE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 3, 'INACTIVE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 1, 'ACTIVE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 1, 'ACTIVE' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | MANAGER |
> | --- |
> | 1 |

---

If you want to include all managers, even those without employees, then you can use:

```sql
SELECT m.id AS manager
FROM   managers m
       LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e
       ON (e.manager = m.id AND e.status = 'INACTIVE')
WHERE  e.manager IS NULL;
```

Which outputs:

> | MANAGER |
> | --- |
> | 2 |
> | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7079efb6675fdbd7f85b74d9ee85abcd)*

Answer (score 0):

This query returns manager 1 and 2;

```
SELECT m.id 
FROM managers m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM employees e 
    WHERE m.id = e.manager 
        AND e.Status = 'INACTIVE' 
        AND ROWNUM =1);
```

But manager 2 has no employe wheter active or inactive. If you want to eliminate manager 2;

```
SELECT m.id 
FROM managers m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM employees e 
        WHERE m.id = e.manager 
            AND e.Status = 'INACTIVE' 
            AND ROWNUM = 1)
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM employees e 
        WHERE m.id = e.manager 
            AND e.Status = 'ACTIVE' 
            AND ROWNUM = 1);
```

2nd query may lead a performance issue due to having more than one sub queries. You can prefer join if you want to eliminate manager 2. But I give second query to show an example of this approach anyway.